# Change windows language by javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to change windows language by `javascript`? I want change windows language on load of page for user not forced to change it manually.

Comment: Define "windows language." Do you mean "Windows language" (the language Windows is currently using)? Or "the window's language" (note the apostrophe), as in, the language being used in the browser window (and if so, what do you mean by that, as the content of the window is whatever the page showing is). Or...?

Comment: Windows Language. Like `En, Az, Tr, ..`. that are installed on `windows OS`

Comment: @SiamakFerdos: I really hope JavaScript can't change OS settings.  Also, what if the user isn't using Windows?

Comment: @David: `Javascript` can detect OS. So may be there was a method like `win32`'s that  can do it.

Comment: If client os is not windows, like iOS , Linux, ... then what happen?
Or If Javascript can do it then the client is not safe from your web site or web service. Javascript just effected on self browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot change the Windows language from browser-based javaScript. The security implications of allowing browser-based JavaScript to modify operating system settings like that are...significant. As yet, I'm not aware of any common API that would provide for it. (Nor are we likely to see one any time soon.)

Comment: I'll use browser of clients on a LAN network. So I don't have any worry about security and I can grant any access is needed to `javascript` or web browsers. So yet there's not any way at all?

Comment: @SiamakFerdos: If you were using an older version of IE that supports ActiveX, you might be able to do it via some ActiveX object. But modern IE doesn't support ActiveX, and of course other browsers never did.