# Change writing language at browser

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I want change language on browsers. I asked for change system language on this post: [How change system language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30681743/change-windows-language-by-javascript) and the answer I've got was Impossible!

I saw before at some websites, by English system language, I could write in other language without changing the system language. Google has something like this too : [google changing language](https://www.google.com/intl/en/inputtools/try/)

How can I do this on some of the my form's input?

Comment: That's Good question LIKE :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to map all keyboard buttons clicks to new layout

```
var charMap = {
   'en': {
       '13': 'enter',
       '54': '6',
       ...
    },
    'lt': {
        '13': 'enter',
        '54': 'š',
        ...
    }
}

$('.input').on('keyup', function(e) {
  var char = charMap[lang][e.which];

  $(this).val($(this).val()+char);
});
```

Check [THIS](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes) page for keyboard kodes

Comment: but which coding should I use? And Aren't there any library do this?